# Can't install Socket.IO on Windows 7 (x32)

Tags: windows, node.js, installation, socket.io

I've been trying to install the Socket.IO module for Node.js without success, The first time I  tried by installing with the following npm command:

```
npm install Socket.IO
```

It didn't work, then I tried by downloading their github repository as a zip file, placing it into the node_modules folder, extracting the file into a folder named "Socket.IO" and trying again the command:

```
nmp install Socket.IO
```

Neither worked, I renamed the folder because probably had the same name as the default root I showed before, neither worked.

BOTH cases, gives me this output:

[image: Socket.IO error.]

I'm guessing that the second form tries to download the sources instead of installing from the folder I specify. What could it be? A connection error? it says "SSL Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED", should I configurate the type of connection or something else? or even better, is there any *easier* way to install Socket.IO?

Comment: I'm on Windows, running as admin (system32) and I don't think it's a problem of privileges

Comment: Stupid comment. My bad. Sorry.

Comment: @Sanjeet Shuag, your comment was not valid but not stupid, I've seen REAL stupid things in life, trust me this is not one of them :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your npm is updated, if it is you could try `npm config set strict-ssl false` to ignore the error.

It seems this is related because npmjs.org changed certificate.